# WCF returning NULL values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

I am calling a third party WCF service in MVC application. 
When I am trying to read the response from service, I am getting all values as NULL, while if I check in fiddler it is showing response there.
Do I need any special configuration which I am missing in code? Please bear with me, as I am a new learner of WCF

Code is as below

```
SalesReviewMD efm = new SalesReviewMD(Server.MapPath("~/Cert/CertGlobal.pfx"), "*****");

    @string stSales = new @string();
    stSales.Value = "slo:cv";
    IdentificationType salesJune = new IdentificationType();
    salesJune.IdentificationID = stSales;
    SaleType salesJuneType = new SaleType();
    EntityType entity = new EntityType();
    entity.id = "7yt678-0330-12312d-238-d4ww444f";            
    DateRangeType dt = new DateRangeType();
    DateRangeType[] dtte = { dt };
    SalesListType request = new SalesListType();
    request.DocumentSubmitter = entity;

    request.SendingSalesProfileCode = "urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-salesList:schema:xsd:WebServicesMessaging-2.0";
    SalesListResponseMessageType response = efm.GetSalesList(request);
```

**SalesListResponseMessageType  from Wsdl**

```
  [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.7.2612.0")]
        [System.SerializableAttribute()]
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
        [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-salesList:schema:xsd:WebServicesMessaging-2.0")]
    public partial class SalesListResponseMessageType : QueryResponseMessageType {
    -------------------
    -------------------
    }
```

Comment: I think you should put your code here

Comment: Added code. But there is nothing as much. Creating request object and calling service method GetSalesList(), in fidder it is showing proper data but in code response has all object as NULL

Comment: did you get data before ?

Comment: No. Just in fiddler textview, everything is correct but not in code

Comment: which is your ServiceReference here? you should have a servicerefencese .. didi you add reference your wcf service in your project ?

Comment: `SalesListResponseMessageType ` is a data type you used in WCF service ? if not so you will get null data . so change it to `Var` or a specific datatype that you used it to return data in wcf service

Comment: 1. yes added reference in project
2. Yes it returns SalesListResponseMessageType , still I'll check with var

Comment: it can be a serialization issue, have you checked out the data returned or have you tried to get data from fiddle and deserialize it?

Comment: I am not calling service using fiddler. I am calling it through code and just inspecting the response in fiddler

Comment: var doesn't helps. It still has Null values

Comment: Did you create the class `SalesListResponseMessageType` on your own or is it auto generated by Visual Studio trough a wsdl?

Comment: It is autogenerated through wsdl

Comment: updated in code

Comment: @Dominik as discussed updated service reference but still no luck

Comment: What is IDE you are using?

Comment: Visual Studio..